# FileReader trying to read hexadecimals, java

Tags: java, file, hex, sublimetext, filereader

I have a file I want to read into my java project. It contains hexadecimal data. The file I have does not have a file-extension, which is how I'll have to work with it because that's how the program will receive the files.

I know I have the right file, because in Sublime Text it opens like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TyUx.png

Nice and hexadecimal. ... But open the same file in Gedit...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqstx.png

Complete chaos. When I then attempt to open the file in my project the way I know how,

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(url))) {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        byte[] sj = line.getBytes();
        char[] charLine = new char[line.length()];
        line.getChars(0, line.length(), charLine, 0);
    }
} (catch and stuff below)
```

Gets me a byte array that is like

```
525 = -65
526 = -67
527 = 15
528 = -17
529 = -65
530 = -67
531 = 15
532 = -17
533 = -65
```

and so on in a system that shouldn't possibly be able to get negative numbers. And in my char array...

```
525 = '\u000F' 15
526 = '�' 65533
527 = '\u000F' 15
528 = '�' 65533
529 = '\u000F' 15
530 = '�' 65533
531 = '\u000F' 15
532 = '\u0003' 3
533 = '\u0010' 16
```

Values that are only 15 in the char-array is sometimes -65 and sometimes 15 in the byte-array, and none of them look like the hexadecimals in the sublime file. I know the bytes/chars each represent two symbols in the sublime file, but... yeah.

I am honestly quite stumped. How do I properly read hexadecimal numbers from this file? Like how Sublime opens it?

Comment: The file is just a binary file, it doesn't contain hexadecimal numbers. Sublime is just showing them to you as such.

Comment: `Reader` implementations are for reading text. This isn't text.

Comment: I'm confused. But, does that mean that Sublime tricked me into thinking things about the file that actually wasn't the case at all? Now that I think about it, it was only because of Sublime that I figured it contained hexadecimals at all.

Comment: Sublime is just trying to show you some representation of the content. Since it isn't text, it doesn't make sense to show you gibberish so it shows you a hex dump.

Comment: Right. So maybe that explains why this has been feeling so impossible. I've been doing this all wrong. I have no idea why sublime does that, but, eh, as long as I know it. Onto googling what to do with binary files, then. Thank you.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'hexadecimal data'. There is data in a hexadecimal *representation*, in which case all you have to do is parse it with `Integer.parseInt()` with a radix of 16, or there is *binary* data, in which case you shouldn't be using `FileReader` at all, you should be using maybe `DataInputStream` around a `FileInputStream`. Unclear what you're asking. And don't post links as part of your question. Material that forms part of the question must be posted *here.*

Comment: Images require 10 reputation to be posted, hence links. I assumed the data was meant to be hexadecimal due to how Sublime opened it. I have googled am currently using InputStreams for it, yes. I am unsure how it could be unclear what I was asking when it was in the very bottom of my question, I wanted to know how to represent the data and was informed I was way off with my means. That's about that.

Answer (score 0):

I write a code that transforms one line of hex into array of integers so i think that this is what You want.
In shotrt - code takes one line of text from file with You presented on first photo and trim to hex values as one strin then splits in to array of Strings and decode for signed values of Integer and returns array of integers. I have tested ths code manualy so there is main() below. Sorry for languange byt hen You see time of this post You will Undestand :) - 01:00 AM :)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

    /**
     * Created by maciej.brzozowski.83@gmail.com on 2017-04-03 01:00AM.
     */
    public class hexDecoder {



        public  int[] decode(String inputString){
            inputString= inputString.substring(inputString.indexOf(" "));
            inputString= inputString.trim();
            String hexArray[] = inputString.split(" ");
            int[] intValuesOfHex = new int[hexArray.length];
            for (int i = 0; i <hexArray.length ; i++) {
              intValuesOfHex[i]=Integer.valueOf(hexArray[i],16);
              }

        return intValuesOfHex;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
           String hexToDecode = "33  c60f cc0f d20f d80f de0f e407 ea0f f10f";
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new hexDecoder().decode(hexToDecode)));
        }

    }
```